# Have to use Response data to another request as Json in Karate

Tags: api, karate

In karate, I want to use the Response data(Scenario 1) to next or another request(Scenario 2) as Json.

I'm not able to pass it with def also. Can anyone help

Scenario 1: POST : User
Given path '/authentication/v1/token/passwordless'
And headers headers
And request { username : '#(activeUsername)' }
When method POST
Then status 200
And print response

- def passwordLessToken = response.tokenValue
  And print passwordLessToken

Scenario 2: POST With Session Detail : Valid Token from Passwordless
Given path '/authentication/v1/token/ltpa'
And headers withPasswordHeaders
**And request { tokenName : '#(tokenName)', tokenValue : +'passwordLessToken' }**
When method POST
Then status 200
And print response

Comment: Can u please confirm in which format have to pass the Value in Json?
Scenario: User
Given path '/authentication/v1/token/passwordless'
And request { username : '#(activeUsername)' }
And print activeUsername
When method POST
Then status 200
And print response
And match response.tokenName == Respo[0].tokenName
* def passwordLessToken = response.tokenValue 
And print passwordLessToken  

Given path '/authentication/v1/token/ltpa' 
And headers withPasswordHeaders
And request { tokenName : '#(tokenName)', tokenValue : response.tokenValue }
When method POST
Then status 200

Comment: that's a very basic question, search for answers or open a new question please